# Duplicity backup to onedrive client error

Tags: python, python-2.7, backup, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I'm trying to make backup of files on my computer in onedrive with duplicity.
I have installed all dependencies, when running duplicity there is the auth link generated which I must open in browser and than in duplicity after giving permissions for app paste the return url.

I do all this steps but duplicity is returning me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1364, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1116, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1005, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/onedrivebackend.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.initialize_oauth2_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/onedrivebackend.py", line 153, in initialize_oauth2_session
    authorization_response=redirected_to)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 232, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 409, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 376, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 383, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py", line 271, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) The client does not exist. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the application management site at https://manage.dev.live.com/.
```

It looks like there is no app with ID which duplicity generate auth link with.
But when I go to the link provided by duplicity I see that "Duplicity is asking for permissions".

So should I add my own app and in some way provide its id to duplicity? (I was searching how to do it but without result) or is it a duplicity bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All programmatic interaction with Windows Live requires a client ID,
>   which uniquely identifies your application to Windows Live. Your
>   application must include the client ID in every request that it sends
>   to the Messenger Connect API Service.

You have to register your application as shown in this official Windows Live tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff751474.aspx

And then pass your ID to the application to be able to authentificate in Windows Live in execution time when asking to the API.

You can use the code in
https://github.com/fkalis/bash-onedrive-upload
which also provide full support for upload files which size is bigger then 100MB

Comment: of course I know that :) I made all steps but still not working, found other bash script for upload and now works great.